# how to increase the row space(Horizontal space) in dataGrid in flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I want to increase the row space(Horizontal space) in DataGrid in flex

no i want horizontal space between every row.
eg.

```
dataGrid Header --   ID  Name
1st row         --   01  A
Horizontal Space--
2nd row         --   02  B
Horizontal Space--
3rd row         --   03  C
```

Like this. I want to increase this horizontal space

Comment: Are you just wanting to add cell padding? Are you just needing to specify the column widths? Can you be more specific with your question?

Comment: i want 1 line space between datagrid rows.

Comment: so you want every other row filled with data?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the width of the column you want to set a specific size to.  In the first column in the example below I am setting the column width to be 100px wide.

This example is taken from the live docs.

```
    <mx:DataGrid id="dg" 
        width="100%" height="100%" rowCount="5" dataProvider="{employees}">
        <mx:columns>
            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="name" headerText="Name" width="100"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="phone" headerText="Phone"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="email" headerText="Email"/>
        </mx:columns>
    </mx:DataGrid>
```

Comment: I am not talking about width of column.I want 1 line space between datagrid rows.

Comment: you might want to change you question to better reflect what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a itemRenderer to the column that uses a padding of x.

i.e.

```
<mx:DataGridColumn width="200" dataField="name" >
<mx:itemRenderer>
    <fx:Component>
        <mx:VBox paddingBottom="20" >
            <s:Label text="{data}" />
        </mx:VBox>
    </fx:Component>
</mx:itemRenderer>
```